# What happens with "removed" bytes if I truncate a File in Java?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a file with the size of 1mb. Now I do following:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(new byte[0]);
fos.close();
```

When I write a empty byte array to a file, what happens with the "removed" bytes? Do they still exist on the file system? Are they still somehow connected to file (e.g. flagged)? Does this make a difference than just deleting the file?

Thanks.

Comment: What removed bytes? `byte[0]` in a `byte[]` is one byte. Alternatively, a `byte[]` of `0` length is **zero *bytes***.

Comment: If the files has 1mb and now I write byte[0]

Comment: You mean you are truncating the file?

Comment: Yes I am truncating the file

Comment: Doubts in comment proves that your question is too broad or unclear, please, provide some sample code or a [mcve]

Comment: The bytes are (typically) still there, and can be recovered at least in part.  File un-delete does this.  But the sectors that you actually write to will be changed permanently.

Comment: If you override your file with a zero-length byte array, then from the point of view of Java, your file now consists of zero bytes. You can now go get some filesystem-specific file recovery tool, and then try to recover some of the bytes from your hard drive, but that's none of Java's business.

Comment: If you truncate a file, the bytes will be gone from all normal file APIs for that file. Whether the bytes are still alive on the FS depends on the FS. Writing a zero-length byte array to a file does not truncate it, but opening it for writing and truncation (whether or not you write) will.

Comment: Why don't you *just* try and *see*?

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin If I now use a file recovery tool, can this detect that the "removed" bytes have been part of this file?

Comment: Does this change anything than just deleting the file?

Comment: Take a look: https://youtu.be/TmDkktcm-Ls

Comment: This overwrites the file with a new, empty file.  "File recovery tools" are going to be hugely dependent on the external filesystem and we can't hope to guess what they'll find.

Comment: Another good reading (it is for NTFS): https://whereismydata.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/file-system-mft-technical/

Comment: Modern OS can hold the history of the files and revert them to the chosen point (depends of your settings). This question is not related to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java point of view data which were in the file before the write call are simply gone. On most operating systems calling this write method will actually result in the file been open for writing, which in turn (in the case the file already exists) truncates the file. As for the underlying storage itself this will disassociate storage blocks (sectors, clusters, extends...) from the file itself marking them free. On a traditional hard-drive, the data itself might be recoverable, but on a flash based storage the information of the block been marked free is actualy delivered to the chip too (TRIM) and data are virtually gone for good.

Comment: Trimming on flash based storages makes them then "unreadable"?

Comment: You would need to dig into the raw storage itself, physically hooking the pins and such, if the block is marked free, a request to read it will return a block full of 0s (in the case of NOR) or full of 1s (in the case of NAND) by the controller which sits between the system bus and the flash chip itself. (if the storage device is emulating the traditional storage 0s are returned in both cases).